# Fresh texlive install cannot compile documents, unable find `article.cls` among many other errors

Tags: latex, tex-live

I recently uninstalled the apt version and switched to the tlmgr version (I think that's what it's called?) in an attempt to fix the issue.

My file is simply:

```latex
\documentclass{aricle}
\begin{document}
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa 
\end{document}
```

Running `latex file.tex` displays:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./error.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-01-09> xparse <2020-03-03>

! LaTeX Error: File `aricle.cls' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)

Enter file name: X
```

I get similar results with `pdflatex`, `xelatex`, and `lualatex`.

Despite all that, if I try to compile a (much larger) file on my dropbox it works just fine. Also if I write the exact same file in `echo` in the same directory it works:

```
$ echo '\documentclass{article}\begin{document}aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\end{document}'| latex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
**entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-01-09> xparse <2020-03-03>
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def)
No file texput.aux.
[1] (./texput.aux)
Output written on texput.dvi (1 page, 272 bytes).
Transcript written on texput.log.
```

Running `cat file | latex` produces the same error as before, and concatenating the lines together doesn't help either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a typo: you wrote `\documentclass{aricle}` instead of *article*.